# Studio apartment only has 2 prong outlets, I need to plug my PC into a 3 prong one

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, ground

I recently built my PC, and it is plugged into a 2 prong outlet through a surge protector using a cheater plug, but I get slight shocks when touching the case. While I can remedy that just by not touching my case, I'm afraid that I might damage the components in the long term due to the PC not being grounded.

The apartment does have a 3 prong outlet, however it is located in the bathroom (right above the shower head), and I don't know if using a really long extension cord from the bathroom would be a safe option.
I'm thinking of connecting the ground tab of the cheater plug to the one of the screws on the breaker panel box using a long copper wire, but I am also unsure if this would provide a proper ground and if it would be a safe option as well.

Getting an electrician to change the outlets from 2 prongs to 3 prongs is out of the question during this pandemic as I live in the Philippines and our apartment building doesn't allow any one who doesn't live here to go in.

Any advice would be great

[image: panel looks something like this]

Comment: Ouch. From a bunch of other questions here, Philippines wiring is *a big mess*. In theory, routing a ground wire by any means available is a good idea. In practice, there may be complications. Pictures of the panel and the receptacles involved ("above the showerhead"???) may help. Also, is this 120 or 240?

Comment: Its 220V, I'll try to provide pictures as soon as I can because I'm currently at work. Though the panel looks something like the picture above, and the panel we have at the apartment seems to be painted, so I was thinking of scraping some of the paint around one of the screw holes with sandpaper so the copper wire has a better connection to the panel box.

Comment: Can you route ground wires from the other outlets to the grounded outlet?

Comment: Is that safe? I could try, but again the grounded outlet is in the bathroom, idk what would happen if the ground wire got wet.

Comment: @AizleDrapiza -- if your bathroom gets water in the walls on a regular basis, then you have bigger issues

Comment: First, you ought to obtain two breakers (any size will do) and install them where those empty holes are (one with a half-broken knockout).  Right now curious fingers could get in there and get killed or burned badly.

Comment: Those slight shocks only are slight because of favorable conditions. In less favorable conditions, they could kill you dead. It sounds like a problem with the PC's power supply, possibly cheapness.

Answer (score 1):

There is some cause for concern if you're getting a shock from the case of your computer.  There should normally be no voltage between the earth and the case.  Adding a green wire will bond the case to the earth and you won't feel that shock any more, but there may be current on that equipment ground wire, which is a problem.  So while grounding the receptacle is a good idea and a safety improvement, it may only mask a problem with your computer, not fix that problem.

Running a green wire (at least #14) for the ground terminal of that receptacle to your breaker panel is electrically sound, and even code compliant by the recent revisions of the NEC, IF and only if the case of your breaker panel is  bonded to an equipment grounding / safety ground system.

This is not a perfect test, but you could run an extension cord from that receptacle to your panel, and test for continuity / resistance between the neutral slot on the extension cord and the panel metal case.  You want to see continuity and very low (practically zero) resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you determine if the screw(s) holding the cover-plate of the two-prong outlets are connected to a **good** ground? In many countries, before grounded outlets were deployed, the receptacle box was grounded through [armored (BX) cable](https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/bx-as-a-ground.125168/page-3). Since that may be questionable in your location, check local rules and, perhaps check resistance to an earth ground or the ground lug of the grounded bathroom receptacle. Be sure you check while passing a current of a few amps, e.g. from a hefty battery or low-voltage transformer.